# how can I convert a negative log likelihood to likelihood?

Tags: probability, likelihood, hidden-markov-model

how can I convert a negative log likelihood to likelihood between 0 and 1 ?

I use HMMs package in R and  I keep getting strange results of the log likelihood for example, -48569 !
I need to understand these values so I can pick the best model.
any advice will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Simple answer: **you cannot**. First, because likelihood is *not* a probability. Second, if you are dealing with continuous data, then you have log-densities and (non-logged) densities are not in [0, 1] and cannot be "converted" to probabilities.

Comment: thanks. I suppose there is a way to represent the values of log likelihood in much better ways. I want to train a discrete hidden Markov model not a continuous.

Comment: Still, likelihood is not probability. If it will "look nicer" for you you can exponentiate it, but it still will not be a "probability",

Comment: thanks , I have updated the question. My background is computing not statistics that's why I thought they are the same. but the purpose of my question is to get more understandable values of the likelihood. using the exponentiation gives me 0 !!

Comment: Your question is "I have $-\log L$, how do I get $L$". This seems to be a question of basic algebraic manipulation. Where's the difficulty in undoing those two steps?

Answer (score 6):

The log likelihood is the log of the likelihood. To get the likelihood from the log likelihood just take the exponential:

$$\text{Likelihood} = e^{\text{Log Likelihood}}$$

This should result in a very small number. Instead you can get the "avg. likelihood" by line in your dataset that is easier to interpret :

$$\text{Avg. Likelihood} = e^{\frac{\text{Log Likelihood}}{\text{Number of Lines}}}$$

Now, what I'm going to say may be true for most basic models, but not for every model.

For a **discrete dependent variable** $Y$, the likelihood is a probability between 0 and 1. For a **continuous dependant variable** $Y$, it is the value of the probability density of $Y$ and may not be smaller than 1. This can be interpreted as a probability by units of $Y$.

Anyway, this probability (or density) may not have a very clear meaning. It is not, like in Bayesian analysis, the probability that the parameters are correct. It is the probability that such data is observed given the fitted model.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. so what do you think if I did the following :  -48569 = log(1/48569) which gives -10.79074 , then convert log to probability using  10.79074/ (1+10.79074) = 0.91 .                  is this correct ?

Comment: No. The log of minus the log likelihood is nothing meaningful.

Comment: What your are doing this way is create an increasing function from the log likelihood to get between 0 and 1. It is nice for visualizing it as a "score". But it is not a probability.

Comment: For the same kind of model (same way of computing the log likelihood), then a higher log likelihood means a better fitted model. The best fitting model is the one with highest log likelihood (sign must be kept, I mean -2000 is higher than -3000).

Comment: many thanks and sorry I make it a long conversation!  what if I keep getting better and better models ? when should I stop to avoid overfitting ?

Comment: It's another question. Browser for existing questions and maybe create a new one

Comment: Are you sure that that's how you get the Avg. Likelihood??

Comment: @BenoitSanchez what exactly is meant here by "number of lines"? Do you mean for example in MCMC the number of draws?